# NoReverseMatch in 'a href' HTML link

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

I'm trying to make a link that redirects to another page in my django application, I have the view, I have the url and I have the template, all are ok in my eyes, but when I try to 'href' the page to do the link I get the Following error:

> Reverse for 'views.candidate_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword
>   arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Candidate, Criterion, Evaluation
from django import forms
from .forms import CandForm
from .forms import EvalForm
from .forms import TestForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.db import IntegrityError

def canditate_list(request):
    candidates = Candidate.objects.all()
    evaluation = Evaluation.objects.all()

    ######################## Ponho todos os candidatos e suas respectivas médias em um array em formato dict({Candidato:N})
    sum = 0
    cont = 1
    med = 0
    lista = []
    for cand in candidates:
        cont = 0
        sum = 0
        med = 0
        for e in evaluation:
            if cand == e.candidate:
                sum += e.score
                cont += 1
        if cont > 0:
            med = sum / cont  

        data = {str(cand):med}              ## a Key recebe o candidato no formato string
        lista += [data]

    ##### passo os dicionários contidos na lista anterior para outra lista convertendo-os em string
    lista2 = []
    for l in lista:
        lista2 += [str(l)]

    lista2 = [re.sub(r'[^\w\d.:]+',"",e) for e in lista2]

    eval_cand_list = []                                     #aqui guarda uma lista com os FK candidates convertidos p/ str
    context = {
        'candidates': candidates,
        'evaluation': evaluation,
        'lista2':lista2
    }
    return render(request, 'app/candidate_list.html',context)

def candidate_detail(request, pk):
    candidate = get_object_or_404(Candidate, pk=pk)
    c_name = candidate.name                                 #pega o nome (string) do candidato
    c1 = Evaluation.objects.all()                           #guarda tds Evaluation na variavel  
    scores = []                                             #declara a array que vai receber as notas
    for c in c1:                                            
        cand = str(c.candidate)                             #guarda o nome do candidato do Evaluation atual
        if cand == c_name:                                  #confere se o Evaluation atual corresponde ao candidate atual(pk)
            scores += [c.score]

    soma = 0                                                #variavel que guardara a soma declarada
    for s in scores:
        soma += s                                           #faz a soma dos scores

    average = 0 
    if len(scores) > 0:
        average = soma/len(scores)                              #tira a média

    context = {
        'candidate': candidate,
        'average': average,
    }

    return render(request, 'app/candidate_detail.html', context)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.canditate_list, name='canditate_list'),
    url(r'^candidato/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.candidate_detail, name='candidate_detail'),
    url(r'^cadastrar/$', views.register, name='register'),  # <--! o cadastro fica num link independete
    url(r'^grid/$', views.grid, name='grid'),
    url(r'^candidato/[0-9]+/avaliacao/$', views.evaluation, name='evaluate'), 

]
```

**template html:**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load mathfilters %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Lista de candidatos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
    <link href="{% static 'css/app.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">   
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="h1t">Lista de Candidatos</h1>
    {% for l in lista2 %}
        <p class="tr"><a href="{% url 'views.candidate_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{l}}</a></p>
    {% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The solution lies within the value of `lista2`. Show the values of `lista2` and we'll be able to answer.

Comment: These values are taken from QuerySet.They can vary, how do you want me to show the 'list2' values? Do you want me to post one for one of them?

Comment: Yes. Just post one, if this is a big list. I just want the pattern to appear.

Comment: Is just a string man, a dictionary converted a string

Comment: That is not very helpful! You are iterating this list and you want to *get* a `pk` from each item to pass it to the `{% url %}` tag. Somewhere, inside this list lies this `pk`. Right?

Comment: I don't know man, That's why I created this topic...

Comment: That's why we can't help you, either! You must provide some of the elements of the `lista2` list. I'm assuming that you **should not** iterate over this. Instead you should iterate over the `candidates` QuerySet.

Comment: It's a list of strings, thats strings are dictionaries converted in string...this dctionary receive the candidate and your average, I converted in string for better viewing...at the moment the list have four elements: Candidato1:1.5

Candidato2:1.0

Candidato3:4.5

Candidato4:4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate over the `candidates` QuerySet instead of the `lista2` list. Then you can do it like this:

```
{% for candidate in candidates %}
    <p class="tr">
        <a href="{% url 'candidate_detail' candidate.pk %}">{{ candidate }}</a>
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: But I need show the candidate and your average,for this reason I create a loop that put them in a dictionary and converted him to a string for better viewing...Is there a way to do this redirect using the list of strings?

Comment: Sorry, I had been wrong, it works ... but why can not I do that with the list of strings?

Comment: Because strings are not `Model` objects that you can call attributes on them (`list_element.id`). The string has no attribute `id`. It's just a plain string. I'll update my answer to fit your needs. Although, it'll not be very elegant.

Comment: hmm ..got it, thank you very much for your attention..So, I need to pick the candidates who are in the querry set candidates (who are a model) and take their suuta average of their notes, which are in another model, do you know if there is any way to have common attributes with same value in models many different? The candidate averages are in the Evaluation model ... or some way to access attributes from other models ... (or is it better to create another question just for this?) Thanks again!

Comment: Better create another question for this! Maybe [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) might be of a help to you. If any of the above answers helped you mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `href` to the following:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load mathfilters %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Lista de candidatos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
    <link href="{% static 'css/app.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">   
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="h1t">Lista de Candidatos</h1>
    {% for l in lista2 %}
        <p class="tr"><a href="{% url 'candidate_detail' post.pk %}">{{l}}</a></p>
    {% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```

In Django, when referencing a view using `url`, you need to use the `name` attribute that you have defined for it in the `urls.py`

Screenshot from OP: file[image]

Comment: Thanks for the attention, but it's don't works: Reverse for 'candidate_detail' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['candidato/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']

Comment: @DouglasdaSilva. That's because `post.pk` is not defined. You're iterating over the `lista2`. Does each element inside the `lista2` has a `pk` attribute?

Comment: @SreetamDas the screeshot is attached